# Convert Command line to a service in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: background-process, ubuntu-16.04, systemd, start-stop-daemon, bitcore

> When I am running a command bitcore-node start it starts two services.
>   Screenshot of ps aux is attached.

[image: >]

> I created a service in /etc/init.d

```
description "Bitcoin Core for Bitcore"
author "BitPay, Inc."

limit nofile 20000 30000

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

kill timeout 300
kill signal SIGINT

# user/group for bitcore daemon to run as
setuid ubuntu
setgid ubuntu

# home dir of the bitcore daemon user
env HOME=/home/ubuntu

respawn
respawn limit 5 15

script
  exec bitcore-node -conf=/home/ubuntu/love/data/bitcoin.conf -datadir=/home/ubuntu/love/data -testnet
end script
```

> I am getting error to while running it.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD5]qT.png

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You have written a script as an Upstart Init Script, and executed it as a SysV init using the systemd init systemd.

You could try placing the script in `/etc/init/` instead of
`/etc/init.d`. That way, it might be processed as the Upstart init script that it actually is.

However, Upstart is being replaced with `systemd`, so following a tutorial on translating your Upstart init script into a systemd `.service` file is recommended.